# can't install ros-electric-openni-camera

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when $sudo apt-get install ros-electric-openni-camera
That's a error:
E: Unable to locate package ros-electric-openni-camera
how to fix this problem?
thanks for any help!

I have runned the instructions from the installation page and I have built rgbdslam. So I am using Electric and not Fuerte.
When came to the Usage:
roslaunch rgbdslam kinect+rgbdslam.launch
the error came, as followed:
Cannot locate installation of package openni_camera: [rospack] couldn't find package [openni_camera]. ROS_ROOT[/opt/ros/electric/ros] ROS_PACKAGE_PATH[/home/sean/ros:/opt/ros/electric/stacks]
So I thought I haven't installation the package openni_camera and I have tried to install it using "sudo apt-get install ros-electric-openni-camera
". However, the problem came!
I haven't tried apt-get install ros-electric-openni-kinect.
Can ros-electric-openni-kinect work? What's the different between them?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44532/can%27t-install-ros-electric-openni-camera/) by [seanbyxm](https://answers.ros.org/users/3252/seanbyxm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-09-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2012-09-24**:
Did you run the instructions from the installation page to set up your apt sources? Are you really using Electric and not Fuerte? Did you run apt-get update first? Have you tried apt-get install ros-electric-openni-kinect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general, I think you may want to look at the differences between [packages and nodes](http://answers.ros.org/question/9133/packages-vs-nodes/) and how [nodes](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Nodes) are a subset of [packages](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Packages). I believe you are trying to run the [openni_camera_deprecated](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_camera_deprecated) node, and looking at that page it seems that node is deprecated, meaning it is no longer being developed. If you wanted to run that node then you would install the [openni_kinect](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect) package. Since it is deprecated though, it is recommended that you use [openni_launch](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_launch) and [openni_camera](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_camera) in Electric and later. There is some ambiguity here, because when you go to the page for the recommended packages it says they are available for Fuerte and later.

The end result is that you should try to install the `ros-electric-openni-kinect` package with

```
sudo apt-get install ros-electric-openni-kinect
```

Then, try running with one of the provided launch files. Also, there is a lot of documentation that will help you get started on those pages above.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2012-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0